# Log result from BulkByScrollResponse Elasticsearch java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete documents on Elasticsearch. For this I'm using `RestHighLevelClient`, then I'm creating `DeleteByQueryRequest` and sending a request like this:

```
BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = client.deleteByQuery(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
```

Currently, I'm logging documents like this:

```
System.out.println("Total documents processed: " + bulkResponse.getTotal());
System.out.println("Total documents deleted: " + bulkResponse.getDeleted());
```

How can I log all the documents that are processed / deleted ?